# Will be going to get engaged

Tags: grammar, future, will-be-going

Is it okay to say:

> He will be going to get engaged to his ex-girl friend.

Is there a better of saying this?

Comment: The constructions *will be* and *going to* both put things into the future. Using them both is redundant and ungrammatical, except if you have a time machine. Use "He will be getting engaged" or "He is going to get engaged". It's possible that you mean something other than "he will be getting engaged". If you do, the sentence above does not convey your intended meaning.

Comment: @PeterShor- What do you mean by time machine? Could you explain it a little bit?

Comment: @Noah: I'm going to go back in time and put right my typo. When the machine stops moving, *I will just be going to type the word* (see the little thinks-bubble saying "I am just going to type the wrod"?)

Comment: Take your time machine to the point in the future when they will be getting engaged at some point further into the future, then your sentence makes sense. Otherwise, as Peter Shor says, it is redundant to use two future constructions together like this.

Comment: *John and his girl-friend have broken up, but after I use my time machine to go back and fix things between them, he will be going to get engaged to his ex-girl friend.* Time travel [weirds](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31532/you-were-already-having-been-going-to-do-that) tenses.

Comment: @PeterShor- Say the person is not getting engaged. And I am just going in time to the future and say: *What if the person that you will be going to engaged to doesn't like you.* Does this make sense?

Comment: We're all going to Vegas this weekend. And John's going too! Really? Why? We told John that Andrea will also be there, so John will be going to get engaged to his ex-girlfriend.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3517/8019. PS: @Jim, you're cheating (equivocating on *going*)

Comment: @TimLymington: yes, I realize the interpretation is different than others have been using.  Nothing in the question points conclusively one way or the other.  My point was just that one doesn't need a time machine to make that series of words grammatical. :-)

Comment: @Jim: ah, rather more subtle than I was expecting.  That would actually be better as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be

> He will be getting engaged to his ex-girlfriend.

Comment: Alternately, "He is going to get engaged."

Answer (score 1):

First, no.  What you have said is not correct.

As for the right way to say it, I'm assuming you mean that they are not engaged yet, but they will be soon.  Maybe he's already bought the ring, but hasn't proposed.  If that's the case, any of these would work:

> He is getting engaged to his ex-girlfriend.
>   Soon, he will be engaged to his ex-girlfriend.
>   He and his ex-girlfriend are soon to be engaged.
>   He and his ex-girlfriend will be engaged soon.
>   He and his ex-girlfriend will be getting engaged.
>   He and his ex-girlfriend are getting engaged.
>   `That last one may imply the engagement is more imminent than the previous example.`

However you choose to say it, good luck to the couple.  Tell them we wish them the best.

Comment: I will. But can we use the 'will be going to' construction at all?

Comment: @Noah, Yes, but only when *going* derives from the verb *to go* (somewhere) and not from the verb *to be going to* (do something). *I will be going to the wedding*; *She will be going to university*; *They will be going to New York*, etc. are all fine.